# C# LINQ select from list of arrays of strings

Tags: c#, linq, select, filter

I have this data

[image]

which is retained in a list of arrays of strings: `List<string[]> arrData = new List<string[]>();`.
The list is filled with the following code:

```
int columnsCount =4;
int rowsCount = 6;
for (int j = 0; j < columnsCount; j++)
{
    string[] columnData = new string[rowsCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
        columnData[i] = csv[i][j];
    arrData.Add(columnData);
}
```

csv[i][j] gives the value for r1c1 etc., so in the end the list has 4 arrays elements, each array having 6 values.

1. How can I use LINQ to select the yellow rows, meaning that have "a" in the first array, "g" in the second one and "m" in the third?
2. How can I use LINQ to filter by a list of values in one column (meaning select all rows with "a" or "b" in first column)?

I can alter the code and create a list of lists / dictionaries / whatever is more suitable.

Comment: how would you do it without LINQ? Did you even tried anything to achieve this?

Comment: You are making it yourself difficult, because you store the data in columns, instead of rows. Storing it as rows makes it a lot easier. So try to swap the outerloop and innerloop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I use LINQ to select the yellow rows, meaning that have "a" in
> the first array, "g" in the second one and "m" in the third?

```
IEnumerable<string[]> result = arrData
    .Where(arr => arr?.Length > 2 && arr[0] == "a" && arr[1] == "g" && arr[2] == "m");
```

> How can I use LINQ to filter by a list of values in one column
> (meaning select all rows with "a" or "b" in first column)?

```
string[] firstColSearch = { "a", "b" };
IEnumerable<string[]> result = arrData
  .Where(arr => arr?.Length > 0 && firstColSearch.Contains(arr[0]));
```

Comment: Did you noticed it is stored as columns? _(not rows)_

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen: I don't think so. I think OP is reading a CSV row by row and value by value and stores them in string-arrays

Comment: It would be easier to store them as rows, so you can select all rows which matches the criteria.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen: But each `string[]` represents a row and contains all values

Comment: Looks like the csv is stored as a jagged array read at ones and read by column (outerloop). The list _`arrData`_ would contain 4 stringarrays each with 6 elements

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen: Maybe there is also a bug. However, the screenshot is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Tim Schmelter's solution worked after I switched the list populating code from columns to rows, as Jeroen van Langen proposed.